# Vim: how can I fix missing commas in BibTeX files?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, latex, bibtex

Often, I start with a BibTeX entry:

```
@book{,
    author = {Person, Some},
    title = {Book},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    year = {2015}
}
```

Then, I discover that the editor is called "Editor" and add the appropriate field:

```
     @book{,
    author = {Person, Some},
    title = {Book},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    year = {2015}
    editor = {Editor}
}
```

Which of course causes problems because I forgot the comma after the `year` entry. Can this be fixed with Vim, either automatically or by marking the error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how often you want to do this, but this will do the trick.

```
:%s/year = {\(....\)}\n/year = {\1},\r/
```

As I understand it

- `s/search/replace/` means search and replace
- `%` means over the whole
  document
- `\(....\)` takes those 4 characters and put them in the place
  of `\1`
- `\r` is a newline

Comment: Well, the thing is that I forget that comma all over the place -- not just for `year`entries!

Comment: How about this: `:%s/^\(.*\) = {\(.*\)}\n/\1 = {\2},\r/`

Comment: I guess that would do the trick, but I'm thinking it could work automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). It has all the functionalities you will ever need to manage bibliography. It is not in the cloud but you can keep your .bib files in dropbox and install Jabref on all your devices for portability.

Comment: I'm familiar with JabRef, but I find it -- and similar tools -- clunky.